# Touches forwarding view above everything else in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiwindow

For a specific enterprise iOS app I need to create a UIView that sits above anything else but that doesn't intercept any touches. I'm currently doing it using a separate UIWindow at UIWindowLevelAlert+1 with userInteractionEnabled set to false like so:

```
self.alphaWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.alphaWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.alphaWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert+1;
self.alphaWindow.hidden = NO;
self.alphaWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.alphaWindow.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
self.alphaWindow.alpha = 1-NIGHT_MODE_BRIGHTNESS;
```

This is somewhat working but there are a few issues.

1. The keyboard is shown above self.alphaWindow.
2. Some UI componennt do not receive touches. For example QLPreviewController is working but when I tap on its sharing button an action sheet opens. In that action sheet I can tap on "Cancel" but touches to any of the other options in the action sheet (like "Copy" for example) do not respond.

Especially the second issue seems very strange to me. How could that be explained?

The purpose of that UIView that sits above anything else is to darken the whole application. Could you think of any better way to achieve that effect?

Comment: You can create same thing with UIView not window. or tell me Specific reason to use UIWindow object ?

Comment: @CodeChanger no specific reason for UIWindow other than that I have no idea how I could add a UIView above alert views and action sheets. Can that be done?

Comment: What you want to achieve by above code ? Dark theme  or brightness ?

Comment: @CodeChanger Brightness, it's a specific client request.